# Spring Hibernate transaction exception rollback

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

**Update 12/12/2011**

The application is making use of a Generic DAO class that can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html).

Based on re-reading the [spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) on the usage of @Repository it would appear that I need to add this to my GenericDAO implementation in order for spring to handle the exception translations.

I added the @Repository to the GenericDAO but, results did not change.  The parent object is still being persisted into the database.

---

Using Spring 2.5.6, JBoss 5.1 with its hibernate version, Spring MVC, MySQL

I am doing some testing to make sure that my transactions will get rolled back correctly in the event of an exception.  In the below code the second method: createProfile will throw a NullPointerException which prevents the method from completing.  I had expected that the transaction would of been rolled back.  What I am finding is that user object is persisted into the database.  What I want is that if the second operation fails then the first operation needs to roll back as well.

I have done some changes in which I changed the propagation to REQUIRED_NEW for the parent method but did not see any changes in the behavior.

I have turned on logging for spring transaction.

I have been looking over different posting here and reviewing [what spring has to say on transactions as well](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).  I seem to be missing something along the lines of transaction behavior.

What am I doing incorrect here.

I have the following defined

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public class ProfileServiceImpl implements ProfileService
    {

      @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
      public boolean createProfile(UserDTO pUserDTO, ContactInfoDTO pContactInfoDTO)
        {
            boolean retVal = false;

            if(this.createProfile(pUserDTO))
            {
                if(this.addAddressToUser(pContactInfoDTO, pUserDTO.getId()))
                {
                    retVal = true;
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
    public boolean createProfile(UserDTO userDTO)
    {
        boolean retVal = false;

        if(this.getProfileQueries().isLoginUnique(userDTO.getLogin(),userDTO.getSiteInfoId()))
        {
            User user = new User();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDTO, user);
            user.setPassword(this.stringDigester.digest(userDTO.getPassword()));
            user.setSiteInfo(this.getSiteInfoDao().read(userDTO.getSiteInfoId()));
            user.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.ROLE_USER);
            user.setStatus(Status.ACTIVE);

            Long pk = this.getUserDao().create(user);
            userDTO.setId(pk);

            retVal = true;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
    public boolean addAddressToUser(ContactInfoDTO pAddress, Long pProfileId)
    {
        boolean retVal = false;

        if(null != pAddress && null != pProfileId)
        {
            ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(pAddress, contactInfo);

            User user = this.getUserDao().read(pProfileId);
            contactInfo.setUser(user);
            this.getContactInfoDao().create(contactInfo);

            user.getUserAddress().setProfileAddress(contactInfo);
            user.getUserAddress().setBillingAddress(contactInfo);
            this.getUserDao().update(user);

            retVal = true;

        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Data config

```
      <!-- TRANSACTION MANAGER--> 
      <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
      </bean>

      <!-- ANNOTATION DRIVEN TRANSACTIONS -->
      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


  <bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/MySqlDS"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
        <value>com.vsg.dataaccess.user.entity.User</value>
        <value>com.vsg.dataaccess.user.entity.ContactInfo</value>
        <value>com.vsg.dataaccess.user.entity.UserAddress</value>
     </list>
    </property>


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
        <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_aud</prop>
        <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">rev_number</prop>
        <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">rev_type</prop>
        <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change">true</prop>        
      </props>
    </property>
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
      <bean class="vsg.ecotrak.dataaccess.framework.hibernate.interceptor.AuditTrailInterceptor"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Need to see how you're actually calling the method.  Would guess the service is self-invoking it and catching the exception before it actually crosses a real proxy boundary.  (or the context is just set up wrong and the transaction manager isn't wired into the entitymanager factory so it's creating the user in auto-commit mode anyway)

Comment: Method is being called from a controller class

Comment: Can you add code for UserDao - how you are managing the hibernate sessions. Are you using hibernateTemplate?

Comment: UserDAO is using a generic dao class.  hibernateTemplate is not being used.  I have updated my orignal information to reflect how the dao layer is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure (in debug mode in IDE) that instance of a class ProfileServiceImpl is wrapped by Spring's AOP proxy (this will mean that Spring Transaction is configured properly), also please provide your *.xml configuration of transaction manager and datasource (etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the autocommit is causing the issue. You would want to turn his off and manually manage the transactions if you want a rollback on first query when second fails . Else the first query will be autocommited. Think about this .